# A Graphics object cannot be created from an image that has an indexed pixel format

Tags: vb.net, vba

I have a program that when you click on picturebox1, it transfers the image inside it to picturebox2. Then I have an interpolation code to modify it to a nearestneighbor pixel rendering. It also draws a pixel grid on picturebox2 to line up around the pixels. I have picturebox2 set to stretch image. I tried 2 different methods of drawing on the picturebox2. I am having a problem converting the image back to the right size to transfer it back to picturebox1 after its been edited with the paintbrush.

CODE:

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
       Dim Brush = Brushes.Black
    Dim COLOR1 As Color
    Dim BMP As Bitmap
    Dim Draw As Boolean
```

CODE: when you click on the picturebox1(topleft) it transfers its image to picturebox2(canvaseditor) does the grid draw, interpolate mode etc.

```
Private Sub topleft_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles topleft.Click
            tiledcanvas.BackgroundImage = topleft.Image
            Label1.Text = "Top-Left"

            'CANVAS PIXEL GRID CODE
            If topleft.Image Is Nothing Then
            Else
                canvaseditor.Image = Nothing
                canvaseditor.Image = topleft.Image
                canvaseditor.Width = topleft.Width * 8 + 1
                canvaseditor.Height = topleft.Height * 8 + 1
                'load and draw the image(s) once
                BackgroundImage1 = New Bitmap(topleft.Image)
                bmpNew = New Bitmap(canvaseditor.Width * scaleFactor, canvaseditor.Height * scaleFactor)
                Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmpNew)
                    g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor
                g.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.Half
                    g.DrawImage(BackgroundImage1, 0, 0, bmpNew.Width, bmpNew.Height)
                End Using
                canvaseditor.Focus()
                GroupBox13.Focus()
            End If
        End Sub
```

CODE: the paintbrush code, the mousedown, mousemove, and mouseup events on picturebox2(canvaseditor)

```
Private Sub canvaseditor_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles canvaseditor.MouseMove

        If Draw = True Then
            PaintBrush(e.X, e.Y)

        Else
        End If


        'If down = True Then
        'canvaseditor.CreateGraphics.FillRectangle(Brush, e.X, e.Y, 8, 8)
        'End If

        ' LocalMousePosition = canvaseditor.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)
        'Dim X As Integer
        'Dim Y As Integer

        'If LocalMousePosition.X > 0 And LocalMousePosition.X < 9 Then
        'X = 1
        ' ElseIf LocalMousePosition.X > 8 And LocalMousePosition.X < 17 Then
        'X = 2
        'ElseIf LocalMousePosition.X > 16 And LocalMousePosition.X < 25 Then
        'X = 3
        'End If

        'Label6.Text = (X & ", " & Y)
        End Sub


    Private Sub PaintBrush(ByVal X As Integer, ByVal Y As Integer)
        Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(canvaseditor.Image)
            g.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(Color.Black), New Rectangle(X, Y, 6, 6))
        End Using
        canvaseditor.Refresh()

    End Sub



        Private Sub canvaseditor_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles canvaseditor.MouseDown
        'down = True
        'If down = True Then
        'Dim NEWBMP As New Bitmap(topleft.Width, topleft.Height)
        'Dim graph As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(NEWBMP)
        ' graph.FillRectangle(Brush, e.X, e.Y, 8, 8)
        'topleft.Image = NEWBMP
        'End If

        'down = True
        'If down = True Then
        'canvaseditor.CreateGraphics.FillRectangle(Brush, e.X, e.Y, 8, 8)
        'End If



        Draw = True
        PaintBrush(e.X, e.Y)





    End Sub



        Private Sub canvaseditor_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles canvaseditor.MouseUp
        Draw = False
        End Sub
```

and heres the first paint sub i made:

```
Private Sub canvaseditor_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles canvaseditor.Paint
            If Not bmpNew Is Nothing Then
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmpNew, 0, 0)
            End If

            Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics
            Dim pn As New Pen(Color.DimGray) '~~~ color of the lines

            Dim x As Integer
            Dim y As Integer

            Dim intSpacing As Integer = 8  '~~~ spacing between adjacent lines

            '~~~ Draw the horizontal lines
            x = canvaseditor.Width
            For y = 0 To canvaseditor.Height Step intSpacing
                g.DrawLine(pn, New Point(0, y), New Point(x, y))
            Next

            '~~~ Draw the vertical lines
            y = canvaseditor.Height
            For x = 0 To canvaseditor.Width Step intSpacing
                g.DrawLine(pn, New Point(x, 0), New Point(x, y))
            Next
        End Sub
```

hoping this is understandable so someone can point me in the right direction. thanks.

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: the mousedown event. i think it has to do with the interpolation mode. either that or the fact that picturebox 2 is way bigger than picturebox 1. i need to somehow make whatever is happening to picturebox 2 go to a bitmap and then transfer that bitmap back down to size of picturebox 1 then send it to picturebox 1

Comment: You mean the PaintBrush() code is throwing the exception?  Everything else is commented out in the MouseDown event.

Comment: well yeah. brought on by the mousedown event. i tried using 2 different methods.

Comment: Sounds like the canvaseditor.Image has a format you can't get a Graphic object from.  You might have to create an image from that image to make it compatible.  See [Graphics.FromImage Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.fromimage(v=vs.110).aspx)